# Substituir múltiplas substrings de um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um replace, mas não estou conseguindo.

Meu código:

```
dicionario = {
    "uva":"R$ 5,00", 
    "abacaxi": "15%", 
    "abacate": "preço: N/A"
    }

for key, value in dicionario.items():
  if 'R$ ' in value or '%' in value or 'N/A' in value:
    dicionario[key] = value.replace('R$ ', 'reais ')
    dicionario[key] = value.replace('%', 'porcento')
    dicionario[key] = value.replace('N/A', 'Nada')

print(dicionario)
```

Output atual: `{'uva': 'R$ 5,00', 'abacaxi': '15%', 'abacate': 'preço: Nada'}`

Output que desejo: `{'uva': 'reais 5,00', 'abacaxi': '15porcento', 'abacate': 'preço: Nada'}`

Por algum motivo que não consegui resolver, apenas o último valor do dicionário está sendo atualizado. Alguém tem alguma luz de onde estou errado?

Comment: Execute cada substituição sobre o resultado da anterior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos modificar um pouco o seu exemplo para entender melhor o que acontece:

```
dicionario = {
    "uva":"R$ 5,00"
}

for key, value in dicionario.items():
    print('substituindo', value)
    if 'R$ ' in value or '%' in value or 'N/A' in value:
        print('antes da primeira substituição: ', value)
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('R$ ', 'reais ')
        print('depois da primeira substituição: ', dicionario[key])
        print('antes da segunda substituição: ', value)
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('%', 'porcento')
        print('depois da segunda substituição: ', dicionario[key])
        print('antes da terceira substituição: ', value)
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('N/A', 'Nada')
        print('depois da terceira substituição: ', dicionario[key])
```

Deixei o dicionário apenas com uma entrada, para simplificar. Depois, eu imprimo o `value` antes de cada chamada de `replace` e o valor de `dicionario[key]` logo depois. O resultado é:

```
substituindo R$ 5,00
antes da primeira substituição:  R$ 5,00
depois da primeira substituição:  reais 5,00
antes da segunda substituição:  R$ 5,00
depois da segunda substituição:  R$ 5,00
antes da terceira substituição:  R$ 5,00
depois da terceira substituição:  R$ 5,00
```

Repare que o `value` nunca muda, pois a chamada de `replace` não modifica a string: o que ela faz é retornar **outra** string modificada.

Então você primeiro troca o "R$" por "reais", e modifica o valor do dicionário (`dicionario[key]` recebe o valor da string modificada, mas `value` continua tendo o "R$").

Depois você tenta trocar o "%" por "porcento", mas como `value` não tem "%", ela não é modificada. E esse valor não modificado (ainda com o "R$") é colocado em `dicionario[key]` - ou seja, o valor anterior ("reais 5,00") foi sobrescrito, e `dicionario[key]` passou a ser "R$ 5,00".

---

Se a ideia é fazer todas as substituições, as chamadas de `replace` devem ser encadeadas. Algo assim:

```
dicionario = {
    "uva":"R$ 5,00", 
    "abacaxi": "15%", 
    "abacate": "preço: N/A"
}

for key, value in dicionario.items():
    if 'R$ ' in value or '%' in value or 'N/A' in value:
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('R$ ', 'reais ').replace('%', ' porcento').replace('N/A', 'Nada')

print(dicionario)
```

Mas acho que  isso só faz sentido se uma string puder ter mais de um desses elementos.
Por exemplo, se tiver a string `R$ 1,00 - 10%`, ela se tornaria `reais 1,00 - 10 porcento`.

Mas se cada string só pode ter uma dessas opções (ou ela tem só "R$", ou só tem "%", etc), aí não precisaria trocar todas as possibilidades, bastaria trocar somente o que ela tem:

```
# no caso de uma string só poder ter uma das opções
for key, value in dicionario.items():
    if 'R$ ' in value:
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('R$ ', 'reais ')
    elif '%' in value:
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('%', ' porcento')
    elif 'N/A' in value:
        dicionario[key] = value.replace('N/A', 'Nada')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui entender bem onde estava o problema! abs =]